# Reopen SASS Mixins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass

Is there a way to redefine SASS mixins. I want to override SASS mixins for site specific styling needs. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My quick bit of testing seems to show that you can override mixins without a second thought. You can't reopen them to the extent that would allow you to override only certain attributes, but you can easily replace them entirely.

#### sample.sass:

```
=test
  color: red
  font-weight: bold

=test
  color: blue

p
  +test
```

#### sample.css:

```
p {
  color: blue; }
```

Note that this test was performed using Haml/Sass 3.0.2 (Classy Cassidy), so this may not hold true for earlier versions, if you were getting an error before.

Comment: if you're gonna override why not make the color customizable instead or just put a default color if it wasn't declared.

Comment: @corroded - This is just a demo of overriding, which the OP asked about. It's not meant to be an example of good code. But thanks for making sure that newbies don't think otherwise :)

Comment: yup just also suggesting to the OP that there's no need to override if you can just use the mixins as functions that can take in variables :) no offense meant :)