# Rails bootstrap-sass redefine/overload mixins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, sass, mixins

With bootstrap-sass you can overload variables by defining them before importing bootstrap (as in documentation):

```
$btnPrimaryBackground: #f00;
@import "bootstrap";
```

Sadly it doesn't work with mixins since in SASS they can be redefined / overloaded.

What would be the best approach to overload a twitter bootstrap mixins ? So far the only way to do it seems to clone the gem in lib and add modify _mixins.scss or include my custom _mixins.scss after.

Any idea to make this more maintainable ?

Comment: If you're changing `mixinA` to do something in addition to its original job, what's wrong with calling the new version `projectname-mixinA`?

Comment: Have to agree with @cimmanon . Could you give an example on what you’re trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to override a twitter bootstrap mixin (in my case formFieldState). I cannot change the name of the mixin since it will be called inside twitter bootstrap, and not by me. Same thing as with a variable, if it's not called $btnPrimaryBackground then it won't be used inside bootstrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the post, [Reopen SASS Mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943863/570918), it is possible to override mixins.  However, if you define your custom one prior to calling `import "bootstrap";` the one defined inside Bootstrap will override it. On the other hand, if you place it *after* the import, all the Bootstrap code has finished compiling by the time you redefine the mixin (see [Issue #240](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/240) and [Issue #420](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/420)).  There is a potential that support for this latter option may be added in the future.

Until then, one option I can think of (haven't tested) would be to separate out the variables and mixins from the **_bootstrap.scss** in order that you can redefine the mixins prior to use.

First, comment out the first two import statements in the **_bootstrap.scss**:

```
// Core variables and mixins
//@import "bootstrap/variables"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc
//@import "bootstrap/mixins";
```

Then in your SASS file which imports Bootstrap, it should be changed to include those:

```
$btnPrimaryBackground: #f00;

// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

// Override of mixin for form field states
@mixin formFieldState($textColor: #555, $borderColor: #ccc, $backgroundColor: #f5f5f5) {
  // customization here
}

@import "bootstrap";
```

Under this workflow, you'd still be editing the vendor files, but at least you could restrict it to merely a couple lines commented out.

Comment: Like the idea! Didn't think of only putting _boostrap.scss in vendor! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I took a similar approach to @merv's answer which is worth a mention. This approach doesn't involve editing vendor code, but does take control of some vendor code. Therefore, there will need to be some thought around version changes if bootstrap is updated in the future.

So originally you would @import "bootstrap"; and this would reference the bootstrap.scss file which then imports all of its dependencies with several other @imports lines. We want our code to hook into the middle of this pipeline to override the bootstrap mixins. I simply copied the entirety of the contents of the bootstrap.scss file and inserted into my my main.scss file and then placed my "Custom overrides" in:

main.scss

```
/*
    Import all scss files from here 
*/
@import "utils";
@import "fonts";
@import "variables"; 

/* 
    Bootstrap imports are being done here rather than importing bootstrap.scss so that mixins can be overridden

    If bootstrap is updated from the version below, ensure all imports are in sync with the new version
*/

/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

//************* CUSTOM OVERRIDES
@import "overrides";
//*************

// Reset and dependencies
@import "bootstrap/normalize";
@import "bootstrap/print";
@import "bootstrap/glyphicons";

// Core CSS
@import "bootstrap/scaffolding";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/code";
@import "bootstrap/grid";
@import "bootstrap/tables";
@import "bootstrap/forms";
@import "bootstrap/buttons";

// Components
@import "bootstrap/component-animations";
@import "bootstrap/dropdowns";
@import "bootstrap/button-groups";
@import "bootstrap/input-groups";
@import "bootstrap/navs";
@import "bootstrap/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/breadcrumbs";
@import "bootstrap/pagination";
@import "bootstrap/pager";
@import "bootstrap/labels";
@import "bootstrap/badges";
@import "bootstrap/jumbotron";
@import "bootstrap/thumbnails";
@import "bootstrap/alerts";
@import "bootstrap/progress-bars";
@import "bootstrap/media";
@import "bootstrap/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/panels";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-embed";
@import "bootstrap/wells";
@import "bootstrap/close";

// Components w/ JavaScript
@import "bootstrap/modals";
@import "bootstrap/tooltip";
@import "bootstrap/popovers";
@import "bootstrap/carousel";

// Utility classes
@import "bootstrap/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-utilities";

//******************** End of Bootstrap

@import "mixins";
@import "demo";
@import "logo";
@import "buttons";
@import "links";
@import "forms";
```